# Type Mismatch on Set Var = Me.TextBox.Value?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA. I'm trying to create a text box where I can add in an item code and on the "AddRecord" button click, update a field in that code's row.

I get a Type Miss-match error on Set Code_in = Me.CodeValue.value and I have no clue as to why and no matter how much I search I can't find any answers.
I feel like this must be something really simple I'm missing...

Below is the full Sub.

```
Private Sub AddRecord_Click()

    'Sets printQ of the code writen in Code_Insert to 1
    Set Code_in = Me.CodeValue.value
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update STOCK SET PrintQ = 1 WHERE Code = " & Code_in & ";"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `Set` as CodeValue is a string. If Code field is text then should be surrounded by single quotes. Try below

```
Code_in = Nz(Me.CodeValue.Value, "")
CurrentDb.Execute "Update STOCK SET PrintQ = 1 WHERE Code='" & Code_in & "';"
```

Comment: Great, that solves that line, but now the second line is Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Code = 001B5'. Do you know why I could be getting that?

Comment: Yes, make sure you surround it by single quotes. It should appear as  `Code ='001B5'`  See the code above